# CSS Full width image

Tags: css, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress site using a child theme and cornerstone page builder. 
Cornerstone allows full width images with no containers for normal pages but not posts. How do I make the post include a full width image?

I want to make this: http://www.crestonsolutions.com/test-post/

Look like this: http://www.crestonsolutions.com/blog/how-to-keep-customers-coming-back-to-your-site/

Here is the CSS I've done to the site:

```
    .x-navbar {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: 0;
}
.x-logobar{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.masthead {
height:0px;
}

.x-nav-wrap.mobile {
background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.60);
margin: 0;
}

.x-btn-navbar.collapsed {
color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 979px){
.x-navbar-inner .x-container.max.width {
  width: auto;
  max-width: none;
}
.masthead-inline .x-btn-navbar {
   margin-right: 15px;
}
.x-navbar .x-brand {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
ul#menu-main-menu-1 {
  width: 88%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.x-navbar {
background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.60)!important;

  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

}
.x-nav-wrap.mobile.collapse.in {
   height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 90px;
}
.x-navbar .x-nav-wrap .x-nav > li > a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 46px;
  border: none;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
}

hr.x-hr {
    width: 20%;
    border-top: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.single-post .x-navbar {
  color: black;
}

.single-post .entry-header {
display: none;
}

.single-post .site > .x-container-fluid {
max-width: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
}

.single-post .x-navbar a {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Please add sample code using https://jsfiddle.net/ straight up css is not helpful without come html for context.

Comment: @SkylerJokiel Can't you just view page source using google chrome?

Comment: @cbandara Can't you just provide relevant parts of your code so we don't have to waste our time to inspect your website?